# PHP undefined property in Twitter response

Tags: php

I have a problem with accessing one of the properties in stdClass returned from Twitter api, I'm trying to get property named extended_entities however PHP constantly returns error complaining that the property doesn't exist. I can clearly see it thoug in var_dump. See output:

```
object(stdClass)[597]
public 'created_at' => string 'Mon Mar 23 16:39:25 +0000 2015' (length=30)
public 'id' => int 580046201061580800
public 'id_str' => string '580046201061580800' (length=18)
...
public 'user' => 
object(stdClass)[600]

          ...
  ...
  public 'notifications' => boolean false
public 'geo' => null
...
public 'entities' => 
object(stdClass)[581]
  public 'hashtags' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'symbols' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'user_mentions' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'urls' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'media' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[593]
          ...
public 'extended_entities' => 
object(stdClass)[573]
  public 'media' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[556]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[595]
          ...
public 'favorited' => boolean false
public 'retweeted' => boolean false
public 'possibly_sensitive' => boolean false
public 'possibly_sensitive_appealable' => boolean false
public 'lang' => string 'en' (length=2)
```

I have no problem getting property for example retweeted, created_at etc. in the following way:

```
$response->retweeted  //this returns false
$response->user //returns stdClass
```

however

```
$response->extended_entities
```

or

```
$response->extended_entities->media
```

returns

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$extended_entities

I expect to have object or array respectively. I don't understand why I can access some of the properties and this one not?

Comment: 1. Does print_r($response->extended_entities->media[0]) work at all? Trying to figure out if it's how you're using it.
2. Does this $response->user //returns stdClass....actually just return stdClass meaning the type to you or is it returning the actual object?

Comment: print_r($response->extended_entities->media[0])  gives the same notice as mentioned above (Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$extended_entities ) . $response->user returns object and I can access all its properties.

Comment: That what I want to do is to get media array ($response->extended_entities->media) and iterate over to get links to images it contains, hovewer for some reason I can't access it.

Comment: I'll add more info, I can get $response->entities->hashtags, ...->symbols, ...->user_mentions, ...->urls and they return empty arrays as expected, accessing $response->media = Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$media so this and extended_entities->media give the same result

Comment: I have made different test, this time I put twitter response to array using json_decode($twitterResponse,true). Now I have everything in array and can access everything I need even extended_entities-> media like this $response[0]['extended_entities']['media'][0]. I'm really curious why this works just fine but using object properties doesn't. If someone has got any clue please share. For now I'll stick with array solution.

Comment: Oh...you were printing json encoded data? Yeah that would be your issue with trying to access those values from PHP then. Didn't realize that.

Comment: From your answer I'm assuming that it isn't uncommon thing when dealing with json encoded data and it is better to decode it to array :) From my yesterday's experience I believe this is the right way to go :) Thanks